# Requiring unknown module "tinycolor2" in react-native Movies example

Tags: react-native

I started seeing this exception after reloading the JavaScript for the React Native "Movies" example on Android. Any idea why?

> Requiring unknown module "tinycolor2"

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem after run npm install tinycolor2. thanks.